# Processing incoming emails with Python

Tags: email, postfix, python

I'm developing a web application that requires that a registered username be able to receive emails to:

```
<some-username>@<my-web-app>.com
```

I need a way to be able to process the email with Python once the system has verified the address is in the system.

Assuming you are using Postfix, how can you add a hook for Python to do some post processing, once an email is received?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a pipe alias in the `aliases` file (e.g. `/etc/aliases`).

```
some-username@my-web-app.com |/path/to/somescript.py
```

And then use the normal Python stdlib modules to tear the message apart.

If you need multiple addresses to point to it then have them all aliased to the newly-created alias.

Comment: I definitely need to do some more research on mail servers - I completely underestimated their complexity. I'll assume your solution is correct though, and will follow up once I reached that point, thanks!

Comment: Can you do this also for all emails and for all emails that have a specific domain?

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://www.bmsi.com/python/milter.html) that contains useful information for writing [milters](http://www.milter.org) in Python.

Comment: milters, as much as I love them, are probably not the right tool for this job, as he's looking to accept the messages, not just filter them before delivery.  I'd personally probably use either a .forward file or make it a postfix transport.

Comment: What he is looking for is definitely doable with Python in a milter context. I am doing similar stuff with MIMEDefang, which I did not recommend because he wants a Python interface.